# Как перенаправить аудиовыход на аудиовход?

Tags: java, api, аудио, io

Нужно каким-либо путем **перенаправить аудиовыход** (звук из колонок, наушников) **на аудиовход** (микрофон), дабы потом обработать звук в Sound API, есть ли в JAVA такая возможность? Знаю что Audacity позволяет такое провернуть, но к ней можно обратиться только с python, тем более не хотелось бы добавлять сильную зависимость от другой программы.

Comment: Получи список устройств, используй дефаултспикерс.monitor как устройство захвата. И не надо ничего пересоединять

Comment: Можно поподробнее, не до конца понимаю что ты имеешь в виду, получить список микшеров? Что за метод monitor?

Comment: Не метод, а отдельный микшер. Я в яве не силен.

Comment: Можешь тогда просто поподробнее описать твою идею.

Comment: А  почему нельзя  использовать  стандартные байтовые потоки ввода-вывода?

Comment: Если ты про Sound API он может брать поток только от существующих аудио файлов.